# Download any file type from laravel webpage on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to make download option in my laravel web project. 
Code 1:

```
public function downloadLogo()
{ return Response::download(images/logo.png); }
```

Code 2:

```
$file = public_path()."/images/logo.png";
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/png',);
return Response::download($file, 'logo.png',$headers);
```

None of them works. Any idea?

Comment: Both of your code should prompt a download, except the first code the path should be quoted "images/logo.png", did you make sure that the image is actually accessible (by using your browser to access it eg. <app_url>/images/logo.png) or the app return any error?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps too late but here is the correct way to achieve this :

```
return Response::download( $file , 'logo.png' , array( 'Content-Type' => 'image/png' ) )->setContentDisposition('inline');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

      $file = "images/logo.png";
      $headers = array('Content-Type'=>'application/png');
      return Response::download($file, 'logo.png',$headers);
```